# message unique is in java mail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm working on application that read mail box (pop3 and imap)
to prevent email double reading I'm wandering if there is some kind of message id.
I cann't user approach with reading only unread email or something like that.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look at the MimeMessage.getMessageID() method, the UIDFolder interface, and the POP3Folder.getUID() method in JavaMail?

Depending on your exact requirements, one of them should work.

Comment: MimeMessage.getMessageID() seams exctly what I was looking

Comment: If this is exactly what you where looking for, why not accept it as THE answer?

Comment: guys is it guaranteed that MimeMessage.getMessageID() is unique ?

Comment: Guaranteed?  No.  Highly likely?  Yes.  Nothing prevents you from copying the same message to a folder more than once, resulting in multiple copies of the message, and thus multiple messages, all with the same Message-Id.  Also, some messages won't have a Message-Id at all.